# MS SQL Server equivalent of oracle query

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I am trying to convert the below Oracle specific query to MS SQL Server specific syntax. But i am not able to do join of the two tables getting error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'LEFT'. Please give the MS SQL Sever converted format of the below query. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT UNIQUE 
       '' log_id, 
       21043 campaign_Id , 
       tbk_campaign.online_campaign_id + ' ' + tbk_campaign.promotion_name email_subject,
       '' email_user_id_to_list 
FROM DUAL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbk_campaign c ON 1=1 AND tbk_campaign.campaign_id =21043
```

Comment: We are not going to do your work for you, show us your attempt

Comment: Sorry for posting entire query. Question edited.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't implement `DUAL`, a mythical table that exists because every `SELECT` "must" have a `FROM` clause<sup>1</sup>.

You can replace `DUAL` with something simple like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT '' log_id, 21043 campaign_Id , tbk_campaign.online_campaign_id + ' ' + tbk_campaign.promotion_name 
  email_subject, '' email_user_id_to_list
FROM (SELECT 1 as a) t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbk_campaign c ON tbk_campaign.campaign_id =21043
```

(Also incorporated UNIQUE/DISTINCT change that [Sandip mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43223808/15498))

---

<sup>1</sup>Instead of implementing `DUAL`, SQL Server instead relaxed the requirement and allows `SELECT`s without `FROM` clauses, as illustrated in the subquery in my answer. However, I believe the standards did mandate the `FROM` clause and the use of `DUAL`.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever.

Answer (score 0):

I have update your query as below and it don't throw any compilation error. Replace `UNIQUE` with `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   '' log_id, 
   21043 campaign_Id , 
   tbk_campaign.online_campaign_id + ' ' + tbk_campaign.promotion_name email_subject,
   '' email_user_id_to_list 
FROM DUAL 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbk_campaign c ON 1=1 AND tbk_campaign.campaign_id =21043
```

Comment: Thanks @Sandip Patel.

Comment: `DUAL` doesn't exist in sql server (unless you create it yourself)

Comment: @Honey.. : I think that DUAL is table name and I have only compile in sql not tried with execute